# HTTP request without POJO classes

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I am currently trying to get an auth token given some body of either `application/json` data or `application/www-x-urlformencoded`. This means that i'd be using an map or a POJO class respectively. The issue is that i am going to be receiving any variation of parameters that need to go into a POJO class. For example the auth request could include:

```
clientId :1234
clientSecret : 1235
```

or it can include something like

```
clientId:1235
clientSecret:1234
appid:21345
etc: etc
```

I have no way of predicting what will be in the body so i cant just make every variation of json body as a class.

Is there a way to dynamically create a class, or more preferably, emulate the class in a way that allows me to specify the member variables at runtime?

I need a way to create an object that i can include in my `RestTemplate` `exchange` function that has dynamically named member variables

Comment: Why don't you just create a class with all the fields possible and set them null when they come empty?

Comment: did you try mapping to Java Map class?  `restTemplate.exchange(params, Map.class)`

Comment: i dont know what the possible fields could be

Comment: Did you try using jacksons JsonNode? You should get a tree with only the incoming fields. Mapping would be left to you.

Comment: that was my initial approach, however how do i map the new JsonNode to a custom class that does not yet exist? Whose member variables are still unknown!

Answer (score 1):

Do you need all the potential fields in your pojo? Or can you progress with a subset of known fields? Then you can just define the subset. If you use jackson as a json mapper, it will just discard additional fields as far as I know, unless you tell it to throw exceptions when json contains more fields than the pojo.

Maybe this is of help: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-mapping-dynamic-object

Comment: the issue is that i dont have a way of predicting what the parameters the pojo will contain, it could be any key and value pairing. So generating a class with all possible params then nulling them out wouldnt be a solution